# Partial fraction for integrating

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have been trying to solve the integral $\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)^2 (x^2+1)^3}$. So while trying to get the partial fraction which way is better?  $$\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+1}+\frac{Ex+F}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac{Gx+H}{(x^2+1)^3}$$ or should we expand like this and then proceed $x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$??
Both the cases are complicated. So is there any better way?

Comment: How comfortable are you with doing complex number arithmetic? That will determine which way is better for you.

Comment: This will lead you a *lot* of computation, however you won't fail. This is the result you should obtain if you want to proceed with PFD:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fraction+decomposition+1%2F%28%28x-1%29%5E2%28x%5E2%2B1%29%5E3%29

Comment: If I had to do it, I should proceed as you did and check first where are the difficulties (if any).

Comment: Download this pdf file. I think it is so helpful... http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rit.edu%2F~w-asc%2Fdocuments%2Fservices%2Fresources%2Fhandouts%2F26Integration%2520by%2520Partial%2520Fractions.pdf&ei=fsnUU4bkNsHMygO9z4GwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFIgo9z3nS19DUb63SgV8Isbyg76A&sig2=pfSXKN6C96e2eIXDA0-Iog